# Recovering from chown -R <user> /usr/bin

Tags: permissions, arch-linux, sudo, root

I ran `chown -R <user> /usr/bin` in arch thinking I could easily fix it if anything went wrong. Unfortunately, that has proven to be incorrect.

As a result of this, startx won't run i3 automatically at startup, ping won't work, and loading webpages seems really slow.

I am able to get sudo working by running `chown root /usr/bin/sudo && chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo`, but giving root recursive ownership of `/usr/bin` doesn't seem to reverse the effects of my chmod.

How can I reverse this?